# Overwrite resources

Tags: android, file, resources

Is it possible to overwrite resource from your app?

If so, how can I get the path to pass to the OutputStream?

I tried something like:

```
FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.myapp.test/res/drawable/image.png");
```

but I get a file not found.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources cannot be overwritten. You could, however, check to see if you have an overloaded resource in a file within your application's space and, if so, make use of that instead. This wouldn't translate directly into layout.xml references though, you would need to manage this programatically, without using resource IDs.

Answer (score 0):

For what purpose do you need to override a recourse?

If you want to change a picture (i guess it from your filepath) you might want to save the picture on the [SDcard](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) or if you want the file to be only for your App, you can save it on the [Phone-Memory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

After you saved the new picture you could check if the file exist. If it exists, you load it, if not, you load your standard picture from the recourse.